# Unable to save image path into database

Tags: php, laravel

In my application, every product must have an image. Below is how i upload my image. When i upload the product details, the image path only is not saved into the database.

No errors to show up in my laravel logs. Am i saving the image rightly?

```
  public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id)
    {


        try {
            Event::fire(new ProductBeforeSave($request));
            $product = Product::findorfail($id);
            if ( $request->hasFile('image'))
            {
            $path =  $request->file('image')->store('uploads/catalog/images');

            // ensure every image has a different name
            $file_name = $request->file('image')->hashName();


            // save new image $file_name to database
            $product->saveProduct($request);

            $product->images()->update(['product_id' =>$product->id ,'path' => $file_name]);

        }


            else
            {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'No Image uploaded');

            }

            Event::fire(new ProductAfterSave($product, $request));


        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception('Error in Saving Product: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

**Image**

```
 public function products()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
        }
```

**Product**

public function images()

```
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
    }
```

Comment: I think Product hasMany Image relationship not Image hasMany Product!

Comment: @HirenGohel i have updated by model

Comment: Try to add like in image model: `return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);` and in product model: `return $this->belongsToMany(ProductImage::class);`

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in your Relationships.

Secondly, you cannot update the many to many relationship like this

`$product->images()->update(['product_id' =>$product->id ,'path' => $file_name]);`

You need to have `where` clause in your query.

`$product->images()->where("some condition")->update(['product_id' =>$product->id ,'path' => $file_name]);`

Hope this helps

Comment: I think OP has already find the product first in `$product = Product::findorfail($id);` and then OP update it. So there's no need for where condition when update!

Comment: i have actually updated my model. i made an error when pasting my codes.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, I am making the assumption that you are adding a new image rather than updating an existing relation.

The `create()` command would be appropriate on the relation and you would also not have the need for the "product_id" field as this would be h

```
// Create a new image for the product
$product->images()->create(['path' => $file_name]);
```

Now in full this would be as follows

```
public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id)
{
    /* ... */
    try {
        Event::fire(new ProductBeforeSave($request));
        $product = Product::findorfail($id);
        if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $path =  $request->file('image')->store('uploads/catalog/images');

            // ensure every image has a different name
            $file_name = $request->file('image')->hashName();

            // save new image $file_name to database
            $product->saveProduct($request);

            // Create a new image for the product
            $product->images()->create(['path' => $file_name]);

        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'No Image uploaded');

        }

        Event::fire(new ProductAfterSave($product, $request));


    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        throw new \Exception('Error in Saving Product: ' . $e->getMessage());

    }

    /* ... */
}
```

You also have your models the wrong way around (as pointed out by @Hiren). The models would have only the relations of other Eloquent classes on them.

**Product**

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
}
```

**Image**

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

It would also be advisable is an image is only belonging to one product (a one-to-many relationship) that you use a function named "product" as above.